# how does form_for know the difference when submitting :new :edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller

I've generated a scaffold, let's call it scaffold test.
Within that scaffold, I've got a _form.html.erb thats being render for action's :new => :create and :edit => :update

Rails does a lot of magic sometimes and I cannot figure out how the form_for knows how to call the proper :action when pressing submit between :new and :edit

Scaffolded Form

```
<%= form_for(@test) do |f| %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

vs.
Un-scaffolded Form

```
 <% form_for @test :url => {:action => "new"}, :method => "post" do |f| %>
       <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

#Edit template

## Editing test

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

#New template

## New test

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

As you can see theres no difference between the forms
How can both templates render the same form but use different actions?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It checks [`@test.persisted?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F) If it is persisted then it is an edit form. If it isn't, it is a new form.

Comment: The `action` and `method` are infact based off of `object.persisted?` check: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb?#L441-L453.  So I don't know why this answer was downvoted.  Probably needs a little rephrasing in "If it is persisted then it is an edit form. If it isn't, it is a new form"

Answer (score 10):

It checks if the record is new or not.

```
@test.new_record? # if true then create action else update action
```

Comment: This is was helpful is this check triggered in the form_for helper?

Answer (score 4):

If the `@test` instance variable is instantiated via the `Test.new` class method, then the `create` method is executed. If `@test` is an instance of `Test` that exists in the database, the `update` method is executed.

In other words:

```
# app/controllers/tests_controller.rb
def new
    @test = Test.new
end
```

`<%= form_for(@test) |do| %>` yields a block that is sent to the `create` controller method.

If, instead:

```
# app/controllers/tests_controller.rb
def edit
    @test = Test.find(params[:id])
end
```

`<%= form_for(@test) |do| %>` yields a block that is sent to the `update` controller method.

**UPDATE**:

The precise function that Rails uses to recognize whether or not a record is new is the [`persisted?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F) method.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: if it was def Newness 
@test = Test.new
end

Comment: By Rails convention, the form is routed to controller actions that are _explicitly_ named for CRUD actions. So, yes – the actions would necessarily be named `create` and `update`.